# How to define multiple custom icons in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet, switch-statement, ejs

I tried to add custom icons to a Leaflet map.

```
<% for (let a=0; a<pointers.length; a++) { %>

  switch ("<%-pointers[a].department%>") {
    case "departmentX":
      L.marker([<%-pointers[a].geolocation%>]);
      var icon = L.icon({iconUrl: '/img/photo1.png'});
      break;
    case "departmentY":
      L.marker([<%-pointers[a].geolocation%>]);
      var icon = L.icon({iconUrl: '/img/photo2.png'});
      break;
    default:
      L.marker([<%-pointers[a].geolocation%>]);
      var icon = L.icon({iconUrl: '/img/photo3.png'});
  }

  L.icon({
      iconSize:     [38, 95],
      popupAnchor:  [-3, -76]
  });

  L.marker([<%-pointers[a].geolocation%>], {icon: icon}).addTo(mymap).bindPopup( "<%-<h1>pointers[a].name%></h1>");

<% } %>
```

The right icons are being placed on the right location when I load the map in my browser. However, IconSize and popupAnchor are being ignored.
Is there a possibility to make IconSize and popupAnchor work without adding it to every case in the switch statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own custom icon by extending `L.icon`

```
var myIcon = L.Icon.extend({
    options: {
      iconSize:     [38, 95],
      popupAnchor:  [-3, -76]
    }
});
```

Then use `myIcon` like this:

```
var icon = new myIcon({iconUrl: '/img/photo1.png'});
```